# Can Hibernate's @DiscriminatorColumn mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance strategy, and I need to set a `@DiscriminatorColumn.` in my table

My question is: Can the column that I'm going to use as a `@DiscriminatorColumn` BE MAPPED in my java entity???

I remember once that it did troubles and I had explicitly create another column just for the Discriminator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can map your discriminator column. Be sure to map to the same column name and that the mapped discriminator is of the [correct type](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorType.html)

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public class RootClass{

  @Column(name="type")
  private String type;
```

Comment: Hmmm...Do you know why `discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.CHAR` is considered to be "not safe" by Hibernate and it throws exception for that!

Comment: No, I didnt know that it is considered unsafe and I cant explain why Hibernate is so picky. Does it work for String?

Comment: This is probably [a hibernate bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5798). If you cannot redefine your column, you can try avoiding the bug. Are you using hibernate 3.6? Have you tried using explicit @DiscriminatorValue values for the concete classes? Have you tried switching to a later Hibernate version?